# Ruby to_xml with repeating same nodes

Tags: ruby, xml, hash

I would like to generate something like:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<Test>
  <Car>
    <engine>A</engine>
    <wheels>4</wheels>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <engine>B</engine>
    <wheels>2</wheels>
  </Car>
</Test>
```

but doing:

```
{"Car"=>[{"engine"=>"A", "wheels"=>"4"}, {"engine"=>"B", "wheels"=>"2"}]}.to_xml(:root => "Test")
```

returns:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<Test>
  <Car type=\"array\">
    <Car>
      <engine>A</engine>
      <wheels>4</wheels>
    </Car>
    <Car>
      <engine>B</engine>
      <wheels>2</wheels>
    </Car>
  </Car>
</Test>
```

You see, I don't want the parent node `"<Car type=\"array\">"`
Any idea how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: What you want is not XML. XML must have a single root node.

Comment: I added a root node, and still..

Comment: What are you using to generate the XML? A template? REXML? Nokogiri? We need to see some code in order to give you accurate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this simple case you can use `Array#to_xml` like so

```
values = {"Car"=>[{"engine"=>"A", "wheels"=>"4"}, {"engine"=>"B","wheels"=>"2"}]}.values.pop
#=> [{"engine"=>"A", "wheels"=>"4"}, {"engine"=>"B", "wheels"=>"2"}]
values.to_xml(:root => "Test", skip_types: true, children: "Car")
#=>"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Test>\n  <Car>\n    <engine>A</engine>\n    <wheels>4</wheels>\n  </Car>\n  <Car>\n    <engine>B</engine>\n    <wheels>2</wheels>\n  </Car>\n</Test>\n"
```

So More Concisely

```
{"Car"=>[{"engine"=>"A", "wheels"=>"4"}, {"engine"=>"B", "wheels"=>"2"}]}.values.pop.to_xml(:root => "Test", skip_types: true, children: "Car")
```

Will Return

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<Test>
  <Car>
    <engine>A</engine>
    <wheels>4</wheels>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <engine>B</engine>
    <wheels>2</wheels>
  </Car>
</Test>
```

`Array#to_xml` allows you to pass in `root` and `children` options so you can name the `root` "Test" and the `children` "Car" as requested. If this was just an example and the case is more complex then there could be concerns with this in which case I would recommend looking at [builder](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder) which allows you immense control over nodes and their naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

[How about utilizing the `:skip_types => true` option?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_xml)

```
{"Car"=>[{"engine"=>"A", "wheels"=>"4"}, {"engine"=>"B", "wheels"=>"2"}]}.to_xml(:root => "Test", :skip_types => true)
```

Comment: this only removes the type=\"array\". Parent node is still there

Comment: What's different between parent node `Test` and parent node `Car`? Just rename the key.

Comment: Parent 'Car' can't be renamed, as it is part of the array